# How can I install a package from Octave Forge?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, octave

How can I install a package from Octave Forge? I am using `imresize` function and I get this error

> warning: the 'imresize' function belongs to the image package from Octave Forge which seems to not be installed in your system.

I tried doing this `octave:1> pkg install -forge image-2.4.1.tar.gz`. I got this error.

> error: get_forge_pkg: package not found: "image-2.4.0.tar.gz". Maybe you meant "generate_html?"
>   error: called from:
>   error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/pkg/private/get_forge_pkg.m at line 73, column 9
>   error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/pkg/private/get_forge_download.m at line 26, column 12
>   error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 385, column 29

What are available packages for image processing in octave? How can I install them?

Comment: Doesn't `-forge` mean download and install directly from the octaveforge repository? In which case you would just pass the package *name* i.e. `pkg install -forge image` (you should get the most recent available version for your platform). OTOH if you're trying to install a local tarball that you already downloaded, it would be `pkg install image-2.4.1.tar.gz` (**without** the `-forge`).

Comment: You need also root permission to install in root directories. This means that you need to start octave as root, that is, from a terminal try: `sudo octave` and then `pkg install -forge image`

Comment: You can also install the pre-packaged version of `octave-image` by typing at a terminal: `sudo apt-get install octave-image` followed by your password.

Answer (score 7):

If you  use `-forge` then only put the name  and not the version.

```
pkg install -forge package_name   # (not the version)
```

is what you want

You can alternative do this:-
This is permanent fix.
In your terminal type

```
sudo apt-get install octave-<package_name_you_want> (eg-image)
```

and then in octave type

```
pkg load <pkg name>
```